# Swift filter an array inside a struct by another array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, contains

I've got an array of Profile's (defined from a custom struct), and inside this, I have a [String] of interests.

I want to filter out any profiles which don't match an array of preferences, but can't seem to get my filtering to work.

The error I get is

> "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'.

What am I missing?

Once complete, I'd expect `userProfiles` to contain only John and Harry.

```
struct Profile {
    var name: String
    var interests: [String]
}


var userProfiles: [Profile] = [
    Profile(name: "John", interests: ["Basketball", "Football", "Rowing"]),
    Profile(name: "Andrew", interests: ["Cycling", "Swimming", "Boxing"]),
    Profile(name: "Harry", interests: ["Hockey", "Baseball"])
]


let preferenceInterests = ["Basketball", "Hockey"]


userProfiles = userProfiles.filter({ (userProfile) -> Bool in
    print("\(userProfile.name): \(userProfile.interests)")
    return preferenceInterests.contains(userProfile.interests) //error here
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `userProfile.interests` is an array, so it wouldn't be the element of `preferencesInterests` which contains `String`.

If you think about it, you are trying to see if two sets of interests have anything in common.  This is `Set` intersection.  `Sets` are more efficient for this purpose than arrays because checking inclusion is O(1) instead of O(n).

By making `preferenceIntests` into a `Set<String>` you can use [`.isDisjoint(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853831-isdisjoint) to see if there are any interests in common.  As soon as Swift finds a single interest in common, it will return `false` because the sets contain a common element and are not disjoint.  You'll want to invert that since you want a common interest to return `true`:

```
let preferenceInterests: Set = ["Basketball", "Hockey"]

userProfiles = userProfiles.filter({ (userProfile) -> Bool in
    print("\(userProfile.name): \(userProfile.interests)")
    return !preferenceInterests.isDisjoint(with: userProfile.interests)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `userProfile.interests` is an array itself. Based on your example and expected output of John and Harry, it seems what you are actually trying to achieve is to keep the users who have at least 1 matching interest compared to your `preferenceInterests` input.

To achieve that, you need to change the body of your `filter` and use `contains(where:)` instead of `contains` to check if there is a match in interests.

```
let filteredUsers = userProfiles.filter { userProfile in
    preferenceInterests.contains(where: { interest in userProfile.interests.contains(interest) })
}
```